# Adding Excel upload feature to Employee Timecard Entry doesn't show ProjectTask field

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization to the Employee Timecard Entry screen (EP305000) which enables the Excel upload functionality into the Details tab grid.  I did this by adding the attribute [PXImport(typeof(EPTimeCard))] to the 'Activities' view re-declaration in a TimeCardMaint BLC extension as follows:

```
    [PXImport(typeof(EPTimeCard))]
    [PXViewName(PX.Objects.EP.Messages.TimeCardDetail)]
    public  PXSelectJoin<EPTimecardDetail,
            InnerJoin<CREmployee,
                On<CREmployee.userID, Equal<EPTimecardDetail.ownerID>>,
            LeftJoin<CRActivityLink,
                On<CRActivityLink.noteID, Equal<EPTimecardDetail.refNoteID>>,
            LeftJoin<CRCase,
                On<CRCase.noteID, Equal<CRActivityLink.refNoteID>>,
            LeftJoin<PX.Objects.AR.Customer,
                On<PX.Objects.AR.Customer.bAccountID, Equal<CRCase.customerID>>,
            LeftJoin<PX.Objects.EP.TimeCardMaint.ContractEx,
                On<PX.Objects.EP.TimeCardMaint.ContractEx.contractID, Equal<CRCase.contractID>>,
            LeftJoin<PMProject,
                On<PMProject.contractID, Equal<EPTimecardDetail.projectID>>>>>>>>,
            Where<CREmployee.bAccountID, Equal<Current<EPTimeCard.employeeID>>,
                And<EPTimecardDetail.weekID, Equal<Current<EPTimeCard.weekId>>,
                And<EPTimecardDetail.trackTime, Equal<True>,
                And<EPTimecardDetail.approvalStatus, NotEqual<ActivityStatusListAttribute.canceled>,
                And<Where<EPTimecardDetail.timeCardCD, IsNull, Or<EPTimecardDetail.timeCardCD, Equal<Current<EPTimeCard.timeCardCD>>>>>>>>>,
            OrderBy<Asc<EPTimecardDetail.date>>> Activities;
```

I also set the 'AllowImport' property of the grid to 'True'.  This seems to work ok, except that the 'ProjectTask' field of the upload does not allow mapping - i.e., if you go through the import process, when you get to the field mapping part, you can't map the Excel field for ProjectTask to the grid's ProjectTask.  It just doesn't show up.

Would this be because the source BLC has as delegate method for 'activities' that I didn't reproduce in my extension?

What could be the reason for not allowing mapping to the ProjectTask field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the ProjectTask field is disabled by default, this was solved by adding a parameter to the [ProjectTask] attribute, called "AlwaysEnabled" via the CacheAttached event, as shown below:

```
public class TimeCardMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<TimeCardMaint>
{
    [PXDefault(typeof(Search<PMTask.taskID, Where<PMTask.projectID, Equal<Current<TimeCardMaint.EPTimecardDetail.projectID>>, And<PMTask.isDefault, Equal<True>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [ProjectTask(typeof(TimeCardMaint.EPTimecardDetail.projectID), 
        BatchModule.TA, 
        DisplayName = "Project Task", 
        BqlField = typeof(PMTimeActivity.projectTaskID),
        AlwaysEnabled = true)]
    protected virtual void EPTimecardDetail_ProjectTaskID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {
    }
```